# Sharp and flat errors

Tags: notation, lilypond, accidentals

Why does an error occur during using sharp or flat?

I just added a few more notes with "is" or "es" to my code:

```
         \relative {
      %\key g \minor
     % \numericTimeSignature
      \tempo "Tempo indication" 8=114
      %\time 7/4
      \pad
      \partial 8 % use part of the time
      g'4\fsol
      \pad {d'4\fre d\fre g,4\fsol c4\fdo c4\fdo g4\fsol
      b2.\fsi r4 g4\fsol
      d'4\fre d4\fre g,4\fsol c4\fdo b4\fsi g4\fsol} \undo \pad % using group \pad --start and stop for the group...
      ***c dis d c aes***  % just for examples....

 }
```

What am I doing wrong of using them?

```
Parsing...
C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:85:5: error: not a note name: dis
  c
    dis d c aes  % just for examples....

C:/Users/TOMMY_~1/AppData/Local/Temp/frescobaldi-ro92knuj/tmpi_my1xgx/Aint-Necessarily-So.ly:85:13: error: not a note name: aes
  c dis d c
            aes  % just for examples....
```

Comment: The indentation of the code is a mess. Can you [fix it](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/117458/edit)? You can [edit (change)](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/117458/edit) your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably using a notename language that doesn't *have* "dis" or "aes".  Chord macro names apparently have been chosen with Italian note name conventions, but the actual note name language uses "g" and its ilk, so my guess would be that you have a `\language "english"` line somewhere which would make "gs" and "gf" be the names for g sharp and g flat, respectively.

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. it works when I added "s" and "f" instead of "is" and "es".